# How to update qt version to 5.15.1

Tags: kubuntu, kde, qt, qt5, kde5

i have on kubuntu qt version to 5.12.8, and i need to update it to 5.15.1
i tried to manually install it..the installation folder installs it in /home/Qt.
but when i check the qt version is still 5.12.8

[image]

any idea on how to update it?

Comment: Why do you *need* to update the Qt version?  The only way to update the Qt version in a way that won't break anything else that is Qt Dependent would be to upgrade to the next release of Ubuntu, however it still won't get you to the latest and greatest Qt.  (Ubuntu is not a rolling release!)

Comment: cause there is an annoying bug on hidpi display that has been fixed on qt 5.15.1.. so i need to update it

Comment: If kwin is the application affected, you could try rebuilding kwin only with Qt 5.15.1 from source. That's not impossible. But surely, going KDE Neon or Kubuntu 21.04 is easier.

Comment: @MathieuJ. the bug was fixed in kde plasma 5.20.. it was a bug it didnt work out well in hidpi display

Comment: Yes, I understand, you need to upgrade to 21.04

Answer (score 0):

As you have installed Qt to your home folder, the system should be configured only for that user.

Create a text file named `default.conf` in the folder `~/.config/qtchooser` with the following contents:

```
{path-to-your-Qt-installation}/bin
{path-to-your-Qt-installation}/lib
```

The first line in the file is the path to the Qt binaries and the second is the path to the Qt libraries.

You can then check using:

```
qmake -v
```

Answer (score 0):

from 20.10, you can upgrade to 21.04

using

```
 do-release-upgrade -d
```

I did it on my system and its working well.

Plasma 5.20.5 and Qt 5.15.1

----- Old reply below -----

Probably best to jump on 21.04 daily builds. (hirsute-desktop-amd64.iso)

https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily-live/current/

otherwise, after building Qt 5.15.1 from source, you will also need to rebuild all KF5/KDE/Plasma packages from sources as well.

it's going to be a huge pain.

your other option is KDE Neon.

Kubuntu 20.04 is forever locked on Plasma 5.18
and Kubuntu 20.10, on Plasma 5.19.

ArchLinux, Debian testing and KDE Neon are the known distribution that ships with Plasma 5.20

Plasma 5.21 is scheduled for mid-February and should be available on 21.04 as well.